# Value found but another one not assigned (lists)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, enumerate

Just the easy one which I could not find out why it works like that:

```
cities = ['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Murcia']

for city in range(len(cities)):
    if cities[city] == 'Madrid':
        cities[city] = 1

    elif cities[city] == 'Barcelona':
        cities[city] = 2

    elif cities[city] == 'Valencia':
        cities[city] = 3

    else:
        cities[city] = 4

print(cities)
```

and this one gives `[1, 2, 3, 4]` as it should.

But if I do this:

```
cities = ['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Murcia']
for city in cities:
    if city == 'Madrid':
        print('hey')
        city = 'Kiev'
print(cities)
```

Result is the following:

```
hey
['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Murcia']
```

So, it recognizes `'Madrid'`, therefore prints `hey`, but then does not assign `'Kiev'` to it. However in the first example, using index range, the reassignment is completed perfectly.

Comment: `city` is not a reference to the list element, it's a variable that holds the value that was taken out of the list. Assigning to it doesn't change the list.

Comment: You can use `for i, city in enumerate(cities)` and `city == 'whatever city here'` and `cities[i] = ...`

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Your second piece of code *never modifies the list, or any of the objects in the list*. So you shouldn't expect anything about the list to change.

Comment: But yes, I second that you should read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: "but then does not reassigns 'Kiev' to it"...does not reassign what?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - Line 4 of the code does not reassign Kiev to the list `cities`

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a similar piece of code:

```
cities = ['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Murcia']
city = cities[0]
city = 'Kiev'
print(cities)
```

Output:

```
['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia', 'Murcia']
```

Here, the final output doesn't have `'Kiev'`. And we aren't surprised by this because nothing in the code modified the `cities` list. In your case, you have a `for` loop, but it is the same thing. There is no magic in the for loop that associates its variable to the original list. So changing the value of the `city` variable inside the for loop doesn't change the `cities` list.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration city will be overriden by the next item in your list cities.

If you want that Madrid will be Kiev, than try this:

```py
for i, city in enumerate(cities):
    if city == 'Madrid':
         cities[i] = "Kiev"
```

Comment: well, to be pedantic, it is a global variable in the OP's code